# Cropping top starred lines in chat, responsive

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, responsive-design

I was at a chat room and noticed starred lines cropping:

[image]

---

If I check responsiveness by shaking the thing, it pops in and out:

[image]

---

I saw this in one of my browsers, and checked that happens in all of them, e.g.:

- Opera 63 (August 2019).
- Firefox Quantum 69.
- Safari 12.1.2 (14607.3.9) [Copyright © 2003–2019 Apple Inc.].

These are not all of the browsers I use, but all of these are up to date.

---

I would suggest to collapse completely the `div.sidebar-widget` nesting `div#starred-posts` whenever a part of it is cropped out of the window, if is that something technologically possible - never authored responsive stuff.